# How to locate a certain <>tag from the same tags and extract the text from it? BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was using BeautifulSoup to extract the job title from indeed, there are s span <>tags which one of them contains the title info.

the h2 tag：

```
<h2 class="jobTitle jobTitle-newJob">
  <div class="new topLeft holisticNewBlue desktop">
      <span class="label">new</span>
  </div>
      <span title="Entry Level Software Developer">Entry Level Software Developer</span>
</h2>
```

Here`s a piece of my code sample:

```
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="job_seen_beacon")
for item in divs:
    title_span = item.find('h2', class_="jobTitle")
    title = title_span.find_all(title=True)
```

when running it, I can only get the list that contains the title.

```
[<span title="Entry Level Software Developer">Entry Level Software Developer</span>]
```

How can extract the title text from it, or is there another way to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get It's text property.

```
title = [span.text for span in title_span.find_all(title=True)]
```

My guess, there will be only one title, you can use:

```
title = title_span.find(title=True)
```

Comment: When I replace the method find_all with find, as is shown in your second line of code, I encounter an error: NameError: name 'title' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, but I give it a second try, and it works! thank you a lot, Rahul